# CakePHP: creating a dropdown on homepge through an element problem

Tags: cakephp

I try to create a search function on my homepage where the user can limit the search results by country.

It all works in my posts/index controller whereby the country list is automatically retrieved by a find('list).

However, on the homepage, the country dropdown remains empty. Below some code:
 I try to retrieve the dropdown by using requestAction (please omit 'requestAction is slow from the comments, thanks)

homesearch.ctp ELEMENT:

```
<?php $this->requestAction('countries/getCountries');?>
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post', array(
    'url' => array_merge(array('controller' => 'posts','action' => 'index'), $this->params['pass'])
    ));
echo $this->Form->input('title', array('div' => false, 'empty' => true, 'label' => false)); 
echo $this->Form->input('country_id');
echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search', true), array('div' => false));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

?>

getCountries function in countries controller:

```
function getCountries(){
    $countries = $this->Country->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('countries'));
}
```

Before diving into alternatives (loadmodule('Country') in PagesController etc), I think I am doing something wrong, there is no data flowing back from the requestAction function as debug taught me.

How do you guys wash this cow? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... (please omit 'requestAction is slow from the comments, thanks)

For improved performance, replace:

```
<?php $this->requestAction('countries/getCountries');?>
```

with:

```
<?php $this->viewVars['countries'] = ClassRegistry::init('Country')->find('list'); ?>
```

This approach doesn't generate a second request.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It still does not work, the dropdown remains empty

Comment: Ah, if you want CakePHP to automagically pick up the values (without you manually specifying them to FormHelper), you need to put the variable in `$this->viewVars` (see update).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> function getCountries(){
>   $countries = $this->Country->find('list');
>   if (!empty($this->params['requested'])) {
>     return $countries;
>   } else {
>     $this->set(compact('countries'));
>   }
> }
> ```

and in the element: `<?php $countries = $this->requestAction('countries/getCountries');?>`

man, it's right in the book: http://book.cakephp.org/view/991/requestAction